# Computer doesn't detect my iPhone 7

Tags: data-transfer, iphone

When I connect my iPhone 7 to my computer, the PC does not detect it. My Iphone notifies me that it is connected and the battery is charging but it does not allow me to transfer works data. 
How do I fix it?

Comment: Is iTunes installed?

Comment: Yes, I have installed it.

Comment: How can I fix it? Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to connect your iPhone to the computer trought Wi-Fi and not trought USB cable.
However, in the following link you will find everything you need.

[This is the link](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOs9-_45rUAhWEWhQKHdl7BlwQFggrMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.apple.com%2Fit-it%2FHT204095&usg=AFQjCNEP3DbWbWOXn8IGYtGI0CRktW09RQ&sig2=qiIKFDlfWnPLYNw9LrOcKw)

Comment: @Jonny-89   It would be helpful (and correct) to provide a summary to the solution here, and not via link to an Italian language page. Its great for you guys if you both speak Italian but you are leaving a lot of users out of the loop.

Comment: @rebusB is correct. While there is no problem sharing/posting the link, as a minimum we always encourage answers to briefly summarise what's on the linked page (regardless of its language). This is best practice because links can break over time, so by including a summary your answer will continue to help users in the long term.